# SQL Find duplicates and update value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains duplicate names and emails but with different identifiers and other associated data. In this case, the identifier **does not** have to be unique. Here is an example of the data:

| course | user_code | First Name | Last Name | Email Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| econ | SKNKZ62HR28 | John | Doe | john.doe@gmail.com |
| lang | C6NV4LQS5D4 | John | Doe | john.doe@gmail.com |
| science | H9NNVNWVPM9 | Fred | Doe | fred.doe@gmail.com |
| govt | JVNH2BVTD3V | Jane | Doe | jane.doe@gmail.com |
| math | L2NK8S49N5G | Jane | Doe | jane.doe@gmail.com |

What I need to do is update the `user_code` so that John Doe has the same `user_code` for both courses:

| course | user_code | First Name | Last Name | Email Address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| econ | SKNKZ62HR28 | John | Doe | john.doe@gmail.com |
| lang | SKNKZ62HR28 | John | Doe | john.doe@gmail.com |
| science | H9NNVNWVPM9 | Fred | Doe | fred.doe@gmail.com |
| govt | L2NK8S49N5G | Jane | Doe | jane.doe@gmail.com |
| math | L2NK8S49N5G | Jane | Doe | jane.doe@gmail.com |

I've been able to identify my duplicates with this code:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM attendees a
JOIN 
    (SELECT [Email Address], [Last Name], [First Name], COUNT(*) AS number
     FROM attendees 
     GROUP BY [Email Address], [Last Name], [First Name]
     HAVING count(*) > 1) b ON a.[Email Address] = b.[Email Address]
                            AND a.[Last Name] = b.[Last Name]
                            AND a.[First Name] = b.[First Name]
ORDER BY a.[Email Address]
```

I'm not sure of the next steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a query to return a result set, you can use:

```
select a.*,
       max(user_code) over (partition by firstname, lastname, emailaddress) as imputed_user_code
from attendees a;
```

The best way to do an update depends on the database.  The square braces suggest SQL Server, which has updatable CTEs.  That allows:

```
with toupdate as (
      select a.*,
             max(user_code) over (partition by firstname, lastname, emailaddress) as imputed_user_code
      from attendees a
     )
update toupdate
     set user_code = imputed_user_code
     where user_code <> imputed_user_code;
```